# Setup app links on a react mobile application

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, applinks, android-app-links

Im actually making a mobile app and i'd to setup links to open it when you click on it.
I tried to setup app links but i doesn't seem to work... Here's my code :

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.didierurban.testLenny">
    ...
  <activity
    android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    ...
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.net" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

My assetlink.json (on https://example.net/.well-known/assetlinks.json)

```
// 20210407190840
// https://lenny-girardot.fr/.well-known/assetlinks.json

[
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.didierurban.testLenny",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "D4:DC:31:60:E9:B2:3F:2B:DF:23:33:31:49:D3:10:9F:3C:3A:6F:E6:1D:41:6E:DB:17:A3:3E:DD:1C:9C:6A:46"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "...",
    "name": "...",
    "slug": "...",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "..."
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "..."
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

If app links are not working with react, what can i setup to make it work ?
I also tried to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-deeplink but it seems outdated.

Thank you

Comment: do you want to set a link to your application?

Comment: Yep i'd like to setup a link that :
- Redirect you to a custom URL if the app is not installed (eg. Store link)
- Opens the app to the correct content / screen if the app is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on expo, you first need to specify a `scheme` in your `app.json`. e.g `myawesomeapp`.

your manifest file should also have the same scheme like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.didierurban.testLenny">
    ...
  <activity
    android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    ...
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="myawesomeapp" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

on ios, add it to `info.plist` here

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>myawesomeapp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

you can then open links to your app using the url `myawesomeapp://`

you can also checkout this [library](https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link) for linking to other applications from your react native app

For more info on deep linking in expo, checkout the docs [here](https://docs.expo.io/guides/linking/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but i have a question. If the app is not installed, what will happen ? Nothing ?

Comment: @Lenny if the app is not installed, its possible to setup a link to store, or any other alternative, but that need to be handled on either the server, or the app you are linking from, ``node-deeplink`` can handle this for you, incase you're using another react-native application to link, you can use the library in added in the answer above. Thanks

Comment: Node-deeplink is still working ? When i try to make this my browser block the redirect https://www.casimages.com/i/210407082756807023.png.html
Here's my code
```app.get('/deeplink', deeplink({
        url: "demo://form/555",
        fallback: 'https://cupsapp.com',
        android_package_name: 'pkg.name',
        ios_store_link: 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cups-unlimited-coffee/id556462755?mt=8&uo=4'
    })
)
```
and once again, thanks for the help !

Comment: @Lenny can't read the language so not able to really figure out the problem, but yeah its possible ``node-deeplink`` is no longer maintained, but i believe there may be other free or premium alternatives out there. You're welcome too. feel free to accept the answer if its solves your issue

Comment: well it says "navigation is blocked" i can't use it so, i'll the the ticket open for few hours if anyone has a solution, otherwise i'll accept your answer.